# Display image from database in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, linq-to-sql, gridview

I have a GridView that shows information from a building. I am loading the information into the GridView from a database like this:

```
var buildings = (from t in dc.Towns
                         where (t.userid == userid) && (t.time < DateTime.Now) 
                         join b in dc.Buildings
                             on t.buildingid equals b.buildingid
                             into j1
                         from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         group j2 by j2.buildingname
                         into grouped
                         select new
                                    {
                                        Building= grouped.Key,
                                        Picture= grouped.First().imagePath,
                                        Number= grouped.Count()
                                    });
        gvBuildings.DataSource = buildings.ToList();
        gvBuildings.DataBind();
```

But I can't display the image, it only shows the path where its saved. How can I display the image from the path in the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have column type that can display image, use Image Field and set DataImageUrlField property with that URL, look here for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the images as Image objects with Image.FromFile(string path) and put them into your binding data in place of the path.

e.g.

```
                 select new
                            {
                                Building= grouped.Key,
                                Picture= Image.FromFile(grouped.First().imagePath),
                                Number= grouped.Count()
                            });
```

You'll need some error handling, of course, and I'd also recommend separating your data access code from your display logic, rather than having it all in one method.

Comment: I can not use Image.FromFile. The only option is Image.DisabledCssClass.